# Significance of changes in mean values over time

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mean

I have 5 mean life satisfaction values for 5 different years; I have to find out if there is a significant relationship between the survey year and life satisfaction. How should I proceed?

I was thinking about a t-test, but I am not sure about such solution.

A million thanks to anybody who takes the time to explain.

Comment: t-test can only make pairwise comparison. I would suggest using a regression model. let say fitting a model $LS = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \epsilon$ or $LS = \beta_0 + \beta_{y2} y_2 + \beta_{y3} y_3 + \beta_{y4} y_4 + \beta_{y5} y_5 + \epsilon$

Comment: Hello kitman, thank you for you answer.

In this case, the five different means would be my predictors, but what would be my outcome variable?

Answer (score 2):

With 5 observations you can't do much unless the values are *very different*.

Examples in MATLAB:

*very different*:

```
y=[10 10 15 10 10]';
fitlm([0 0 1 0 0]',y)

ans = 


Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1

Estimated Coefficients:
                   Estimate        SE          tStat         pValue  
                   ________    __________    __________    __________

    (Intercept)    10          9.7334e-08    1.0274e+08    2.0336e-24
    x1              5          2.1765e-07    2.2973e+07    1.8189e-22


Number of observations: 5, Error degrees of freedom: 3
Root Mean Squared Error: 1.95e-07
R-squared: 1,  Adjusted R-Squared 1
F-statistic vs. constant model: 5.28e+14, p-value = 1.82e-22
```

*not very different*

```
y=[9 10 15 12 13]';
fitlm([0 0 1 0 0]',y)  


ans = 


Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1

Estimated Coefficients:
                   Estimate      SE       tStat      pValue  
                   ________    _______    ______    _________

    (Intercept)    11          0.91287     12.05    0.0012299
    x1              4           2.0412    1.9596      0.14491


Number of observations: 5, Error degrees of freedom: 3
Root Mean Squared Error: 1.83
R-squared: 0.561,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.415
F-statistic vs. constant model: 3.84, p-value = 0.145
```

Because your sample size is so small, there's not much you can do. In the simplest model with just one dummy for year 3 you need to estimate 3 parameters on 5 observations. With 5 observations you can barely estimate one parameter reliably, mean.

So, when you have year really sticking out like in the first example, you can be quite confident that its mean is different. In the second example year 3 is different, but given the variation of results in other years this difference is barely distinguishable. The mean is years 1,2,4,5 is 11 and standard deviation is 1.83, so 15 is not that *far* from that mean.

These examples tell you that given a tiny sample size you have find some hypothesis that can be reliably tested on your data. Without looking at the data it's impossible to say what will work.

Comment: this was very helpful. Actually, I have a data set with more or less 10.000 observations over 5 different years, that is more or less 2.000 observations per year. I've obtained the means for each year from specific subsets of the above mentioned data set. How should I use regression to determine if there is a significant relation between survey year and life satisfaction?

Thank you

Comment: In this case I'd start with ANOVA. In my example I'd run ANOVA on year 3 and the rest. You have sample sizes and variances. You can do regression if you think there's a trend and noise is not too high, i.e. trend shows up through the noise.